# Getting current login from Active Directory using C# code

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

How can I get the current user's login name from Windows Active Directory using C# code?

Answer (score 63):

Simply,

```
string Name = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).Identity.Name;
```

OR

```
string Name = System.Environment.UserName
```

OR

```
string Name = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME");
```

OR

```
string Name = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

works :)

Comment: And none of the involve AD which is totally useless here anyway (it does not track who the current user is - after login AD is not really asked too much during a session).

Comment: I have a website and I am trying to get the username of logged in user to Windows and none of the above is giving me that :/

Comment: Thank you so much. I was searching all the time.

Comment: @Sunil you've unchecked my answer, anything I could help you with?

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you!

Comment: Consider CamelCase variable Name?

Answer (score 33):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up, you can use:

```
// set up domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find current user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.Current;

if(user != null)
{
   string loginName = user.SamAccountName; // or whatever you mean by "login name"
}
```

The new S.DS.AM makes it really easy to play around with users and groups in AD!

References:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) (this link has been archived, [use this one instead](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnmagazine/archive/2008/01/16/7120454.aspx))
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Comment: @user1306094: this works in any environment where you have Active Directory in place.

Comment: Hi its Working inside the Domain. How to make it work in different server or outside the Domain

Comment: @user1306094: as I already said - it works **when** an Active Directory is in place. If AD is not there, there's no way to make this work. Not clear why/what you mean *in different server* - it works using the default Active Directory **DOMAIN** - it's not tied to a specific server

Comment: ok. what if i have hosted my application in different server which is not having AD, but it can Access AD where the users resides. can i give the name of AD in PrincipalContext Object.

Comment: i used same code in my Domain and hosted in IIS but Error coming saying: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal' to type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal'. but its running fine in Visual Studio.

Comment: What do you need ´PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);´ for, when "ctx" is not used later?

Comment: @OleAlbers: in this particular case - you don't need it. If you want to search for a user by some name - then you need the context.

Answer (score 3):

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.Current.Name
```

This is also working for me! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was getting "NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" with other solutions offered but 
**System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name.ToString()** 
worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my view and works perfectly for me!

`<h5 class="mb-0 text-gray-800">Welcome, <span style="text-transform:capitalize">@User.Identity.Name.Replace("AD-GROUP-NAME\\", "").Replace(".", " ")</span></h5>`