# Authenticating user against active directory without asking for Credentials

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm a very beginner or unaware about Active Directory. But I have a query to authenticate the user using Active Directory in C# based web forms application. But without asking for any credentials.

I'm not getting an idea where to start or even its possible. They are expecting authenticating the user based on the current system logged in users details from AD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting current login from Active Directory using C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10877614/getting-current-login-from-active-directory-using-c-sharp-code)

Comment: Check this tutorial: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323176/how-to-implement-windows-authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net

Comment: @mariocatch: it's not the duplicate. The OP doesn't want to get the current username in C# code but rather use integrated, Windows auth on their website.

Answer (score 3):

If your web app is running in IIS on Windows, then it is easy. You just need to enable Windows Authentication in IIS. There are more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/), but most of it is just adding this to your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <authentication>
         <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
         <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
      </authentication>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Then in your app you can see who is logged in using `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`.

To let users login seamlessly (so the browser sends their credentials without asking), the website needs to be in the 'Trusted Sites' in the Internet Options (for IE and Chrome anyway - Firefox has its own way). This might already be true in your organization, but if you find that users are being prompted for credentials after you enable Windows Authentication, then this should be checked. It can be set by group policy if you need to.

Comment: Thanks a lot boss. Yea, my app is running in IIS on windows.