# Using logged in identity for seamless authentication with service using LDAP authentication

Tags: windows, authentication, active-directory, ldap, access-token

Let's assume we can not get password of the current user, only username and domain if necessary. Is it possible to get a session token or something similar to authenticate with remote service using LDAP authentication?

**UPDATE**

I am writing a c# app that would get info from a web service written in Python.
Remote web service uses [python LDAP module](https://pypi.org/project/ldap3/) to manage LDAP users and authentication. I'd like to use logged in windows [user identity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10877627/1433554) info to log into remote service. I can modify the authentication logic in remote web service if "token based" or similar authentication is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what type of application you're using, but the only way to do this is with Windows Authentication. For a web application, the web server (IIS, Apache, etc) would handle the authentication and give you the name of the authenticated user.

In ASP.NET, the implementation also depends on if you're using the [.NET Framework](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/323176/how-to-implement-windows-authentication-and-authorization-in-asp-net) or [.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).

To give you any more information, you will need to specify what type of application you're working on and on which OS.

Comment: Updated description.

Comment: If they python app is validating the username and password, then there is no way to authenticate to it without knowing the password. You would have to setup the web service with Windows Authentication for this to work the way you would like.

Comment: I can edit the python app. Is there nothing LDAP provides to authenticate without username and password? Token.. session...

Comment: The token can only be created with the password. So you have to get the token from the C# app to the web app first. To do that, you need to implement Windows Authentication in your web app. Which web server and OS is your python web service running on?

Comment: Debian, framework is [frappe](https://frappe.io/frappe) with [Werkzeug](https://palletsprojects.com/p/werkzeug/) as a webserver .

Comment: You don't have a web server like Apache in front of Werkzeug? [Their documentation](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/serving/) seems to suggest that the built in web server should only be used for development.

Comment: My understanding is that frappe uses Werkzeug in production. Here is [LDAP authentication module](https://github.com/frappe/frappe/blob/master/frappe/integrations/doctype/ldap_settings/ldap_settings.py).